# Making a validation check appear or warning in red letters appear if input field is black once submit is pushed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular, and I have a dropdown box with selections in it and an input text field.

I want the dropdown to be required as a selection once the search button is pressed, and then it will execute a function in the Angular controller. If not selected, I would like red text above the dropdown to appear saying "please blah blah".

How can I achieve this in the simplest way?

This is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Asset Disposal Multi Mill Inquiry</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body><br/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">


        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="mill">
                <option value="">Select a Mill </option>
                <option value="608">Tomahawk Mill</option>
                <option value="610">Valdosta Mill</option>
                <option value="620">Counce Mill</option>
                <option value="622">Filer Mill</option>
                <option value="650">DeRidder Mill</option>
                <option value="651">Wallula Mill</option>
                <option value="652">Jackson Mill</option>
                <option value="653">International Falls Mill</option>
           </select>&nbsp;
        </div>

     <div class="form-group">
                <label>Disposal Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 92%" type="text" ng-model="id" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && search()"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <button ng-click="search(mill)" type="button" class="btn btn-med btn-danger">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

And my angular controller, up to the search function being called:

```
var AssetDisposalMultiMillInquiryController = function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, $modal, $window, AssetDisposalService, CMMSAssetDisposalService) {


$rootScope.title = 'Asset Disposal Multi Mill Inquiry';
$scope.allMills = [];
$scope.mill = '';
$scope.disposalID = '';
$scope.requestor = '';
$scope.disposalNumber = '';
$scope.approvalStatus = '';
$scope.changeAmount = '';
$scope.amountOperator = '';
$scope.id = '';
$scope.amount = '';
$scope.approvalstatus = '';

$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.counce = null;
    $scope.filer = null;
    $scope.tomahawk = null;
    $scope.valdosta = null;
    $scope.deridder = null;
    $scope.whiteMills = null;

};

$scope.search = function(mill) {
    //for each mill
    $scope.reset();
if ($scope.mill == "620") {
    $scope.disposalNumber = $scope.mill + "-" + $scope.id
    CMMSAssetDisposalService.searchMulti("http://localhost:52765/AssetDisposal/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.disposalNumber).then(function (results) {
           $scope.counce = results;
           $scope.counce.forEach(function (item) {
               item.disposalNumber = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.disposalNumber);
               item.jobNumber = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.jobNumber);
               item.requestor = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.requestor);
               item.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.description);
               item.amount = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.amount);
               item.status = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.status);
           });
       });
   }
```

Comment: I dont think it is good practice but you could just put a div with ng-if set to display if the form is dirty and the select is not selected. Or you could set a default selection.

Comment: have a look to the documentation of forms https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean displaying error messages?
You can use [**ngMessages**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages)

Small example:

```
<form name="userForm">

    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="username" 
        ng-model="user.username" 
        ng-minlength="3" 
        ng-maxlength="8"
        required>

    <div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
        <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
        <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
        <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: i see the input textfield how would i apply something like that to a dropdown box?  the first value in the dropdown is an empty string so something not an empty string is what i would be looking for

Comment: You can use required for that, in exactly the same way.